# Populate combobox with unique numbers

Tags: excel, vba

The following code populates `ComboBox` on a `userform` in `vba` with unique values. I use the same code to populate two other `ComboBox`es.

It doesn't work when the data in the column is a number. If I change the number to a text it works. How can I get it to work with numbers also?

```vb
Sub uniqueYear()
    
Dim myCollection As Collection

On Error Resume Next
Set myCollection = New Collection

With Me.cbxYear
    .Clear
    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").range("AC2:AC" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Len(cell) <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            myCollection.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
            If Err.Number = 0 Then .AddItem cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: "doesn't work"  - what does it do exactly *instead* of working?

Comment: Try testing the value using `IsNumeric`.  Then `If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then .AddItem CStr(cell.Value)` or something close to that.

Comment: The `key` parameter to `Add` is expecting a String-type argument.

Comment: @PeterT: Works even without checking, `CStr` will happily convert a String to a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative using a Dictionary

```vb
Sub uniqueYear()
    Dim dict As Object, ar, r As Long, k As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row
        ar = .Range("AC2:AC" & r).Value2
        For r = 1 To UBound(ar)
            k = Trim(ar(r, 1))
            If Len(k) > 0 Then dict(k) = r
        Next
    End With
    Me.cbxYear.List = bubblesort(dict.keys)
End Sub

Function bubblesort(ar)
   Dim a As Long, b As Long, tmp As Long
   For a = 0 To UBound(ar)
        For b = a + 1 To UBound(ar)
            If CInt(ar(a)) > CInt(ar(b)) Then
                tmp = ar(a)
                ar(a) = ar(b)
                ar(b) = tmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    bubblesort = ar
End Function
```

Comment: Can we have it sorted?

Comment: @codist How many item in list ?

Comment: It varies, I use your code in 4 comboBoxes. Items in the list vary depending on the size of the data.

Comment: @codist Try a simple bubble sort - see update. If they are not integers change the Dim to suit.

Comment: I changed `tmp As Long` to `tmp As String` as these are not integers, there are alphanumerics (A300M, XY500),  but I get Run-time error 13 Type Mismatch.

Comment: @codist You need to change the comparison too `If CInt(ar(a)) > CInt(ar(b)) Then` to `If CStr(ar(a)) > CStr(ar(b)) Then`

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd extract the job of collecting unique values to a separate method:

```vb
Sub uniqueYear()
    
    Dim myCollection As Collection, v, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'activeworkbook?
    
    Set myCollection = UniqueCollection(ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))

    With Me.cbxYear
        .Clear
        For Each v In myCollection
            .AddItem v
        Next v
    End With
End Sub

Function UniqueCollection(rng As Range) As Collection
    Dim c As Range, col As New Collection, v
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = c.Value
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            If Len(v) > 0 Then col.Add v, CStr(v) 'Key needs to be a String
        End If
    Next c
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set UniqueCollection = col
End Function
```

Comment: Nice. It runs instantaneously for over a thousand items. The author of [this page](https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Fill_combobox_listbox_en.html) states that `AddItem` is slow and `List` with an array is preferred. Is this related to old versions of Excel or is there some truth to it nowadays?

Comment: @VBasic2008 - I only tested with a relatively small set of values - it it does prove to be slow with larger datasets then converting the collection to an array might something to try out.

Comment: I used this code and accepted this as the answer but I have now changed as I encounter an awkward situation and the other answer which I now accepted did the job without any issues. The awkward situation that I just said is that when the sheet that has the data is selected while showing the `userform` it worked but when I changed selected another sheet while the `userform` is shown some items didn't come in the `comboBox`

Comment: Huh - I can't see how that could happen, since the range passed to `UniqueCollection` only refers to whatever is assigned to the worksheet variable `ws`...